# Проблемы создания загрузочной флешки с ext3 для Linux с загрузчиком extlinux

Tags: ubuntu, boot, live-usb

Обращаюсь с просьбой о помощи в разрешении моей проблемы. 
Необходимо создать загрузочную флешку с файловой системой ext3 для 2-х специализированных ЭВМ на Linux (ЭВМ1 и ЭВМ2).

***Есть:***
1.Незагрузочные ISO-образы (по крайней мере, таковыми их считает Rufus) того ПО, которое должно устанавливаться на эти ЭВМ. В образе ПО для восстановления и ЭВМ1, и ЭВМ2 (выбор идет в процессе инсталляции)
2.Есть одна флешка (назовем рабочей) с ПО для ЭВМ1, способ записи на которую неизвестен. Файловая системы ext3. Загрузчик extlinux
3. Есть отдельно папки и файлы ПО ЭВМ1

***Задача:***
1.Сделать загрузочную флешку с ext3 для Linux желательно с загрузчиком extlinux (назовем тестовой)
2. Перенести на нее папки и файлы ПО ЭВМ1 и убедиться, что процесс загрузки тестовой и рабочей флешек совпадают. Это , в какой-то степени потвердит правильность дальнейших действий.
3. В случае удачи создать по такому же алгоритму флешку с ПО для ЭВМ, записав на нее информацию, извлеченную из ISO-образов

***Почему все так сложно и что сделано:***
 1. Использование всех доступных мне загрузчиков пока не принесло успеха, так как
почти все из них требуют загрузочных образов, а другие не работают с ext3
 2. Почему ext3? В ПО есть файлы типа .symlink, с которыми FAT не работает. Поэтому загрузочная флешка, которую я делал  с FAT32, загрузку начинала и зависала в процессе инсталляции 
 3. Сделано все, что в моих силах. Наилучший результат дал syslinux, но установить его смог только на флешку с с FAT32, загрузку начинала и зависала. Unetbootin  для Win - boot error. Unetbootin  для Linux Ubuntu установить не смог. В данный момент пытаюсь решить вопрос путем создания флешки в Ubuntu, но пока не получается установить загрузчик syslinux или extlinux

Comment: Может лучше рассказать какие образы надо загружать, чем пытаться дать для решения абстрактную задачу?

Comment: При создании флешки руфусом, попробуйте указать, что это DD-образ